# Keyword arguments with do-block

Tags: elixir, syntactic-sugar, keyword-argument

I have a function that looks something like this.

```
def test(options \\ []) do
  # Fun stuff happens here :)
end
```

It accepts several (optional) keyword arguments, including `do:`. I'd like to be able to call it like this.

```
test foo: 1 do
  "Hello"
end
```

However, this gives an error.

> ```
> ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Example.test/2 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:
>
>       * test/0
>       * test/1
>
>     Example.test([foo: 1], [do: "Hello"])
>     (elixir) lib/code.ex:376: Code.require_file/2
> ```

As you can see from the error, the syntax above is desugaring to two separate keyword lists. Now, I can call this function using the following slightly inconvenient syntax

```
Example.test foo: 1, do: (
  "Hello"
)
```

but is there any way to provide a `do`-block in addition to other keyword arguments in one function call?

Comment: Can it be a macro instead of a function?

Comment: I have no qualms with making it into a macro. Do you have a solution that works with a macro?

Comment: I do. I will post it, hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are open to using a macro instead of a function this might help you:

```rb
defmodule Example do
  defmacro test(args, do: block) do
    quote do
      IO.inspect(unquote(args))
      unquote(block)
    end
  end
end
```

Sample usage:

```rb
iex(2)> defmodule Caller do
...(2)>   require Example
...(2)> 
...(2)>   def foo do
...(2)>     Example.test foo: 1 do
...(2)>       IO.puts "Inside block"
...(2)>     end
...(2)>   end
...(2)> end
{:module, Caller,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 4, 108, 66, 69, 65, 77, 65, 116, 85, 56, 0, 0, 0, 147,
   0, 0, 0, 16, 13, 69, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 46, 67, 97, 108, 108, 101, 114,
   8, 95, 95, 105, 110, 102, 111, 95, 95, ...>>, {:foo, 0}}
iex(3)> Caller.foo
[foo: 1]
Inside block
:ok
```

Comment: That is exactly the solution I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 20):

While the answer provided by @bla is technically correct (e. g. `macro` works,) it barely sheds a light on whats and whys.

In the first place, nothing prevents you from having this syntax with a function instead of a macro, you just need to explicitly separate the keyword argument to `do:` part and anything else:

```rb
defmodule Test do
                     # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ HERE 
  def test(opts \\ [], do: block) do
    IO.inspect(block)
  end
end

Test.test foo: 1 do
  "Hello"
end
#⇒ "Hello"
```

What you *cannot* achieve with a function, is to produce *an executable* block. It would be static, as in the example above, because functions are runtime citizens. The code at the moment of function execution will be already compiled, meaning one cannot pass *a code* to this block. That said, the block content will be executed withing the *caller* context, *before* the function itself:

```rb
defmodule Test do
  def test(opts \\ [], do: block) do
    IO.puts "In test"
  end
end

Test.test foo: 1 do
  IO.puts "In do block"
end

#⇒ In do block
#  In test
```

This is not usually how do you expect Elixir blocks to work. That is when macro comes to the scene: macros are compile-time citizens. The `block` passed to `do:` argument of macro, will be *injected as AST* into `Test.test/1` `do` block, making

```rb
defmodule Test do
  defmacro test(opts \\ [], do: block) do
    quote do
      IO.puts "In test"
      unquote(block)
    end
  end
end

defmodule TestOfTest do
  require Test
  def test_of_test do
    Test.test foo: 1 do
      IO.puts "In do block"
    end
  end
end

TestOfTest.test_of_test
#⇒ In test
#  In do block
```

---

*Sidenote:* in comments you stated “I have no qualms with making it into a macro.” This is plain wrong. Functions and macros are not interchangeable (although they look like they are,) they are *completely different* things. Macros should be used as a last resort. Macros *inject AST* inplace. Functions *are AST*.

Comment: Great point!  One should always prefer a function over a macro if everything else is equal.  Functions are much safer and a lot easier to maintain for other developers after you (or maybe you in six months).

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci well, it depends. While functions are easier to write, debug, test, and maintain macros provide the explicit feature of _injecting AST inplace_, which is sometimes of a great help. Check [these from `Stream`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/9bc852b95c9e1d910e643604148bedc2aa6e03d4/lib/elixir/lib/stream.ex#L104-L121) core module. They are way more succinct than the original code and bring very valuable clarity to already cumbersome code. Needless to say, one cannot achieve this with functions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, was wondering what the „do: expression“ syntax in function arguments is exactly doing...